# Locating empty field groups for saving data

Tags: delphi

The aim of the code below is to see if selected fields are empty so data can be saved in that field. Since I'm making a library system, I wanted to record the basic info on one record (all the books they have taken out so the ID's of them as well as author and title) but this proves to be quite tricky and quite long to code.

I was wondering whether there's an easier way to code this instead of the very long `if` loop. It would also help if I could use the same solution (obviously tweaked) when displaying their loans on the form as well.

```
procedure Save;
{ procedure to locate which field groups are empty so product and loan informati
 - on can be saved }
begin
  if LoanRecords.ProductID1 ='' then
  begin
    LoanRecords.ProductID1 := ProductRecords.UniqueId;
    LoanRecords.ProductTitle1 := ProductRecords.ProductTitle;
    LoanRecords.ProductAuthor1 := ProductRecords.ProductAuthor;
  end
  else if LoanRecords.ProductID2 = '' then
  begin
    LoanRecords.ProductID2 := ProductRecords.UniqueId;
    LoanRecords.ProductTitle2 := ProductRecords.ProductTitle;
    LoanRecords.ProductAuthor2 := ProductRecords.ProductAuthor;
  end
  else if LoanRecords.ProductID3 = '' then
  begin
    LoanRecords.ProductID3 := ProductRecords.UniqueId;
    LoanRecords.ProductTitle3 := ProductRecords.ProductTitle;
    LoanRecords.ProductAuthor3 := ProductRecords.ProductAuthor;
  end
  else if LoanRecords.ProductID4 ='' then
  begin
    LoanRecords.ProductID4 := ProductRecords.UniqueId;
    LoanRecords.ProductTitle4 := ProductRecords.ProductTitle;
    LoanRecords.ProductAuthor4 := ProductRecords.ProductAuthor;
  end
  else if LoanRecords.ProductID5 ='' then
  begin
    LoanRecords.ProductID5 := ProductRecords.UniqueId;
    LoanRecords.ProductTitle5 := ProductRecords.ProductTitle;
    LoanRecords.ProductAuthor5 := ProductRecords.ProductAuthor;
  end
  else if LoanRecords.ProductID6='' then
  begin
    LoanRecords.ProductID6 := ProductRecords.UniqueId;
    LoanRecords.ProductTitle6 := ProductRecords.ProductTitle;
    LoanRecords.ProductAuthor6 := ProductRecords.ProductAuthor;
  end
end;
```

This is the record structure-

```
  TLoan = record
    LoanUniqueId: integer; { of loan record }
    DateDue: TDateTime; { date when products are due to be returned }
    MemberUniqueID: integer; { from MemberDetails File }
    MemberName: string[50]; { from MemberDetails File }
    MemberSecondName: string[50]; { from MemberDetails File }
    AmountBorrowed: integer; { amount of items currently on loan }
    { Product 1 }
    ProductID1: integer; { product ID }
    ProductTitle1: string[80]; { product title }
    ProductAuthor1: string[80]; { product author }
    Return1: boolean;
    { has book been returned- true/false- set to false until book is returned }
    { Product 2 }
    ProductID2: integer;
    ProductTitle2: string[80];
    ProductAuthor2: string[80];
    Return2: boolean;
    { Product 3 }
    ProductID3: integer;
    ProductTitle3: string[80];
    ProductAuthor3: string[80];
    Return3: boolean;
    { Product 4 }
    ProductID4: integer;
    ProductTitle4: string[80];
    ProductAuthor4: string[80];
    Return4: boolean;
    { Product 5 }
    ProductID5: integer;
    ProductTitle5: string[80];
    ProductAuthor5: string[80];
    Return5: boolean;
    { Product 6 }
    ProductID6: integer;
    ProductTitle6: string[80];
    ProductAuthor6: string[80];
    Return6: boolean;
  end; { of TLoan- loan details }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Technically, there is no such thing as if-loops. Your code is just a bunch of if-else *statements* (sorry, this was the language police speaking)

What your code actually needs, is actually a real loop. Use an array or a list of a record, `TLoanProduct` and loop through it. Your current approach allows a maximum of six products in one loan, it involves a lot of code duplication which in itself is a code smell, and it could be a bit weird if the values for Product 3 were set but not Product 1.

My Delphi skills are a bit rusty, but consider changing `TLoan` into an `object` or a `class` instead of a pure `record`. That way you could have the `Save` method as part of the `TLoan` object/class.

This is some code for how I think it should look. It's been a long while since I worked with Delphi so this might not be 100% correct code, but it should get you started in the right direction.

```
TLoanProduct = record
    ProductID: integer;
    ProductTitle: string[80];
    ProductAuthor: string[80];
    Returned: boolean;
end;
TLoan = record
    LoanUniqueId: integer; { of loan record }
    DateDue: TDateTime; { date when products are due to be returned }
    MemberUniqueID: integer; { from MemberDetails File }
    MemberName: string[50]; { from MemberDetails File }
    MemberSecondName: string[50]; { from MemberDetails File }
    AmountBorrowed: integer; { amount of items currently on loan }
    LoanProducts: array [0..5] of TLoanProduct;
end;

...

procedure Save;
{ procedure to locate which field groups are empty so product and loan informati
 - on can be saved }
var i: integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to High(LoanRecords.LoanProducts) do
  if LoanRecords.LoanProducts[i].ProductID = '' then
  begin
    LoanRecords.LoanProducts[i].ProductID := ProductRecords.UniqueId;
    LoanRecords.LoanProducts[i].ProductTitle := ProductRecords.ProductTitle;
    LoanRecords.LoanProducts[i].ProductAuthor := ProductRecords.ProductAuthor;
    Exit; // Exit the method so that this is only applied for one element
  end;
end;
```

Comment: wouldn't that write the data (Unique ID, Product Title etc) to each loan product if no items were loaned? so I'd end up having 5 sets of the same data? @SimonAndréForsberg

Comment: @Hawwa You're right. Missed that important part. I've added an `Exit;` statement to end the execution of the method to fix that.

Comment: I tried the above method but for some reason the ProductID, ProductTitle and Author come up with the following error- [dcc32 Error]: E2018 Record, object or class type required

Comment: ...............@SimonAndréForsberg

Comment: @Hawwa I made a few updates to my code here. If this still doesn't work for you, update your question and add a section containing what you are attempting. I also noticed that ProductID is an integer and not a string, so how you would manage to compare it against an empty string goes beyond my comprehension.

Comment: i just did the IntToStr/StrToInt conversion and use length to check that. Thanks for the update the errors have gone :)